# Polymorphic association query multiple JOIN as separate columns

Tags: sql, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to extract a query that needs to access a polymorphic association table in SQL twice (I need to JOIN it on both 'types')

Here is the structure for the SQL tables.

```
Answer: id, user_id
UserGroup (polymorphic): usergroupable_type, usergroupable_id, group_id
User (polymorphic column groupable_type: 'User'): id, name
AdminUser (polymorphic column groupable_type: 'AdminUser') : id, name
Group: id, name
```

I want to query each individual answer from the 'Answer' table, inner join with 'User' table on User.id == Answer.user_id, and inner join with 'UserGroup' table to get the 'group_id' for those with usergroupable_type == 'User' and usergroupable_id == User.id so that I can join to the 'Group' table to obtain the Group.name.

After that, I would like to obtain the AdminUser.name from the 'AdminUser' table by connecting with the polymorphic 'UserGroup' table on usergroupable_type == 'AdminUser'.

Basically, I would like to obtain the Group.name, AdminUser.name per row in 'Answer' table.

Comment: Sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag would all make this much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right then something like

```sql
select g.name, au.name
from answer a
join usergroup ug on
    ug.usergroupable_id = a.user_id
    and ug.usergroupable_type = 'User'
join group g on
    g.id = ug.group_id
join usergroup aug on
    aug.group_id = g.id
    and usergroupable_type = 'AdminUser'
join adminuser au on
    au.id = aug.usergroupable_id
```

Should do it, but if I have misunderstood maybe share some sample data

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you so much! I'm new to SQL so i didnt think of using 'join usergroup __aliased_name__'  hence i was getting an error saying i cant join the same table twice, thank you!

Comment: Ah great, glad it helped, yes, you can join as many times as you want on the same table, fundamentally SQL is all about defining and joining named relations where the name is implicitly that of the table you are basing it on if you omit a name. Hope you have lots of fun with SQL :-)